# How to keep accumulated hours format when importing msexcel to msaccess

Tags: datetime, ms-access

I am importing accumulated hours from an excel sheet to an access database. It will not maintain the format. I have tried changing everything and it keeps reducing the hours to hours/60.

Answer (score 0):

You could import the value as a string and change it back to a time/date value where before you use it. Would that be an option in your case?